# How to get the following $A$-module $Y$ is flat?

Tags: modules, representation-theory, flatness

Let $A$ be a subalgebra of an algebra $B$ such that $J_A=J_B$(here $J_A$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$), then there is an functor $F=Hom_B(B,-): mod(B) \rightarrow mod(A)$. Now let X be a $B$-module, $Y=FX$, then I have seen that there is an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow Y \rightarrow B\otimes_AY \rightarrow B/A \otimes_A Y \rightarrow 0$$ of $A$-modules. Obviously we have an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B 
\rightarrow B/A \rightarrow 0,$$ so to get the first exact sequence, I think we need $Y$ is a flat $A$-module. How to get $Y$ is flat for any $B$-module $X$? Thank you for any help.

Comment: You don't really need that every $A$-module is flat, but just that $A$ is pure in $B$ (actually a bit less, because you only consider modules of the form $FX$).

Comment: @egreg Could you tell me the meaning of that $A$ is pure in $B$? Yes, I don't need every $A$-module is flat. I just want to know why all $A$-modules of the form $FX$ is flat.